# IE5/IE7 table-layout:fixed: Not allowed to have more than 100% width cells in total?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, tablelayout

The following sample does not show the second cell in IE5/IE7 (possibly IE6, too, but I was not able to test it):

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
<colgroup>
    <col style="width:99%">
    <col style="width:15%">
</colgroup>
<tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ullamcorper eros turpis, a placerat diam malesuada porttitor.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ullamcorper eros turpis, a placerat diam malesuada porttitor.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Other browsers prefer the width of the second cell and reduce the width of the first one by themself. Is it not allowed to have more than 100% width in total or is this a bug related to IE5/IE7?

Comment: Out of curiousity: does "IE5/IE7" mean you have to support "IE5" and "IE7", but not necessarily "IE6"? Or does IE6 lack that bug?

Comment: I was not able to test IE6 as it is not part of the IE dev tools.

Comment: I recommend ie7.js — IE7.js is a JavaScript library to make Microsoft Internet Explorer behave like a standards-compliant browser. It fixes many HTML and CSS issues and makes transparent PNG work correctly under IE5 and IE6. — https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/